# (Conditional?) creation of local variables in function

Tags: c, local-variables

I came across this [question]: [How can I store values into a multi-parameter struct and pass typedef struct to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181087/how-can-i-store-values-into-a-multi-parameter-struct-and-pass-typedef-struct-to/57181462#57181462).
I suggested declaring a variable of dtErrorMessage once before the if and use it for both conditions instead of declaring two different variables as shown here:

```
// Initial version
if(GetTemperature() <= -20)
{
    dtErrorMessage low;
    low.errorCode=ERROR_CODE_UNDER_TEMP;
    low.temperature=GetTemperature();
    SendErrorReport(&low);
}

if(GetTemperature() >= 160)
{
    dtErrorMessage high;
    high.errorCode=ERROR_CODE_OVER_TEMP;
    high.temperature=GetTemperature();
    SendErrorReport(&high);
}


// My version
dtErrorMessage err;
int8_t temp = GetTemperature();       // Do not consider change during evaluation

if(temp <= -20)
{
    err.errorCode   = ERROR_CODE_UNDER_TEMP;
    err.temperature = temp;
    SendErrorReport(&err);
}
else if(temp >= 160)
{
    err.errorCode   = ERROR_CODE_OVER_TEMP;
    err.temperature = temp ;
    SendErrorReport(&err);
}
else
{
  // Do not send error report 
}
```

My question is: (Under the embedded aspect,) am I right, that this way there will be two local variables created in RAM regardless of the condition? Consequently, it would reduce the reqired RAM using one unconditional variable declaration before the if and then using it for both conditions, right?

I couldn't find the correct terms to search for getting this answered myself.

Comment: You’re probably wrong. The two conditional variables would probably occupy the same space.

Comment: No, you’re not right about that, and tighter scope is generally cleaner even before taking into account the more descriptive names, so the first version is better imo.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: In that case, it is this due compiler optimisation, I assume? Do you have a reference for this topic? Assuming using the code in a function definition, wouldn't there be two local variables created, right?

Comment: In first version Thehe 2 vars will not exist at same moment due to scope limitation.  So they will probably end in same ram address,  exactly as in second option.  What is really important here is could the temperature change between two call? To avoid any side effects.  In second option,  you can also factorise the sendMessage so I would prefer this option for code size even if compiler may do it

Comment: @Julien: You are right regarding the change of temperature, the safer way would be a variable holding the return value of `GetTemperature()`.
@Ry: Well, the struct variable itself holds the actual description. So, only looking at the variable identifiers, I personally would not mind using the more generic `err` identifier. But that's more a personal thing I guess.
Thanks for your answers everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of a variable with *automatic storage duration* is until the end of the block. Storage will be guaranteed and it will retain constant address (i.e. the address given by e.g. `&`) until the end of the block, and after that all pointers to that object will become indeterminate.

The C standard does **not** say that `low` and `high` must occupy the same portion of memory! The storage must be guaranteed until the end of the block containing the declaration, but it can be around longer too.  On the other hand the as-if rule says that the program needs to only behave as if it was a program compiled for the abstract machine according to the rules of the C standard, so a high-quality implementation would probably

- not reserve memory for both `low` and `high` simultaneously at different addresses, **and**
- not reserve memory for `err` in case the `else` branch is taken.

In effect making the execution behaviour of these 2 virtually identical.

The difference is mostly stylistic: in your version there is less to type, and the original version accommodates for bad compilers.

Comment: Not identical due to getTemp being called twice if temperature changes in first version and not in second.  The rest is clear

Comment: @Julien ah true dat :d well, if there were if-elseif-else ladder